# Does SetWindowsHookEx() work for future processes

Tags: winapi, hook, dll-injection, setwindowshookex

I write a C++ executable running on Windows 7 that calls

`SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, pFunc, hDll, 0 /*dwThreadId*/)`

This installs my hook procedure `pFunc` that monitors messages posted to a message queue.

As MSDN says, if parameter `dwThreadId` is 0, the hook procedure is associated with **all existing threads**. But what I see is, this hook procedure `pFunc` will hook future processes that launched after this hook process. Is this right?

Comment: That's right, future processes are hooked when user32.dll is loaded. Sorry, no reference at hand.